# Docker Desktop for Windows + ASP.NET Core Error

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have recently decided to give docker a try and I'm running into this error for 2 days now. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get rid of it.

For a .NET Core 2.2 application:

`2>C:\Users\Russell\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.4.4\build\Container.targets(256,5): error : An item with the same key has already been added.`

This is freshly added Docker support for the project, no config changes. I've tried a clean, rebuild, updated all nugets, etc. If I run the project in IIS express it runs fine.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Edit 1: Docker file:

````
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SearchAPICore_Search/SearchAPICore_Search.csproj", "SearchAPICore_Search/"]
COPY ["SearchAPICore_Models/SearchAPICore_Models.csproj", "SearchAPICore_Models/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SearchAPICore_Search/SearchAPICore_Search.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SearchAPICore_Search"
RUN dotnet build "SearchAPICore_Search.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SearchAPICore_Search.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SearchAPICore_Search.dll"]```
````

Comment: Post your dockerfile or steps how you got to this error

Comment: file added - all I did was right click on the project -> add -> docker support > linux (windows does the same thing), then tried to run the project in docker via the "run" button at the top of VS in the toolbar.

Comment: This becomes Visual Studio troubleshooting rather then docker. I really suggest don't use VS for anything docker related. Craft your dockerfile manually to understand what those things do

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue as I have ran across the same issue.

Comment: Sadly, no. I'm diving back in next week and will contact docker, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a left over container that's causing the issue. Try cleaning your environment with the following commands:

Linux:

```
# Clean exited containers
docker ps --filter status=exited -q | xargs docker rm
# Clean dangling images
docker images --filter dangling=true -q | xargs docker rmi
# Clean old tagged images 
docker images --filter reference="$ContainerTag" -q | xargs docker rmi
```

Windows PowerShell:

```
# Clean exited containers
docker ps --filter status=exited -q | %{ docker rm }
# Clean dangling images
docker ps --filter dangling=true -q | %{ docker rmi }
# Clean old tagged images 
docker images --filter reference="$ContainerTag" -q | %{ docker rmi }
```

The last one might not be necessary but it can't hurt. Just make sure to either replace $ContainerTag with the name of the image, or create a variable with that value before hand.

Comment: "*The last one might not be necessary but it can't help.*" — I assume you mean "can't hurt"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: No problem - just wanted to make sure my edit was cromulent.